# Error while installing NumPy using pip. × Getting requirements to build wheel did not run successfully

Tags: python, numpy, installation, build, pip

This is my 40 line error code

error: subprocess-exited-with-error

× Getting requirements to build wheel did not run successfully.
│ exit code: 1
╰─> [40 lines of output]
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\msys64\mingw64\lib\python3.9\site-packages\pip_vendor\pep517\in_process_in_process.py", line 351, in 
main()
File "C:\msys64\mingw64\lib\python3.9\site-packages\pip_vendor\pep517\in_process_in_process.py", line 333, in main
json_out['return_val'] = hook(**hook_input['kwargs'])
File "C:\msys64\mingw64\lib\python3.9\site-packages\pip_vendor\pep517\in_process_in_process.py", line 112, in get_requires_for_build_wheel
backend = _build_backend()
File "C:\msys64\mingw64\lib\python3.9\site-packages\pip_vendor\pep517\in_process_in_process.py", line 77, in *build_backend
obj = import_module(mod_path)
File "C:\msys64\mingw64\lib\python3.9\importlib_*init**.py", line 127, in import_module
return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
File "", line 1030, in _gcd_import
File "", line 1007, in _find_and_load
File "", line 972, in _find_and_load_unlocked
File "", line 228, in _call_with_frames_removed
File "", line 1030, in _gcd_import
File "", line 1007, in _find_and_load
File "", line 986, in _find_and_load_unlocked
File "", line 680, in *load_unlocked
File "", line 850, in exec_module
File "", line 228, in *call_with_frames_removed
File "C:\Users\abhij\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-g0qzuyap\overlay\lib\python3.9\site-packages\setuptools_*init**.py", line 242, in 
monkey.patch_all()
File "C:\Users\abhij\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-g0qzuyap\overlay\lib\python3.9\site-packages\setuptools\monkey.py", line 99, in patch_all
patch_for_msvc_specialized_compiler()
File "C:\Users\abhij\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-g0qzuyap\overlay\lib\python3.9\site-packages\setuptools\monkey.py", line 162, in patch_for_msvc_specialized_compiler
patch_func(*msvc9('find_vcvarsall'))
File "C:\Users\abhij\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-g0qzuyap\overlay\lib\python3.9\site-packages\setuptools\monkey.py", line 149, in patch_params
mod = import_module(mod_name)
File "C:\msys64\mingw64\lib\python3.9\importlib_*init**.py", line 127, in import_module
return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
File "", line 1030, in _gcd_import
File "", line 1007, in _find_and_load
File "", line 986, in _find_and_load_unlocked
File "", line 680, in _load_unlocked
File "", line 850, in exec_module
File "", line 228, in _call_with_frames_removed
File "C:\Users\abhij\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-g0qzuyap\overlay\lib\python3.9\site-packages\setuptools_distutils\msvc9compiler.py", line 295, in 
raise DistutilsPlatformError("VC %0.1f is not supported by this module" % VERSION)
distutils.errors.DistutilsPlatformError: VC 6.0 is not supported by this module
[end of output]

note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: subprocess-exited-with-error

× Getting requirements to build wheel did not run successfully.
│ exit code: 1
╰─> See above for output.

note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.

I tried looking online and usually similar errors have missing files or packages so now I'm just expecting to know what's wrong with my pip installation and what fix I can get since when I try to import in IDLE after this it doesn't work

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bpip%5D+VC+6.0+is+not+supported+by+this+module

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
pip install numpy
```

or

```
conda install numpy
```

it works with WIN/MAC/Linux
try to reload or change interpreter
and if nothing will work specify your question more precisely